# select not equal too with loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array with 6 random id. How can I perform
`select * where id not equal to` from my array in php?

I'm trying with a for loop but at first it returns everything except `id[0]`, the second time everything except `id[1]` and so on.

My query look like this

```
select * from challenges where id <> id[i]
```

my array is `catogary_id` and looks like

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 10 [4] => 3 [5] => 5 [6] => 8 [7] => 1 [8] => 7 )
```

The loop

```
for($cnt=0;$cnt<count($cat_id);$cnt++)
{
    $task_id=$catogary_id[$cnt];
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from task id <> $task_id");
    $Qno=1;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: `select * from task WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(id, '$task_id')`, where `$task_id` is the array values joined into one CSV string literal, like `$task_id = implode(',', $cat_id);`. Do not forget to wrap the literal with single quotes. PS. If you use direct insertion then you may use `WHERE id NOT IN ($task_id)` - in that case wrapping not needed (but this is not safe for SQL injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sql = "SELECT *
         FROM task 
         WHERE id NOT IN ( '" . implode( "', '" , $cat_id ) . "' )";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```